# 'npm run start' persists indefinitely while attempting to start the Node.js application on a windows server from Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, localhost, npm-start, npm-run

When using an Azure DevOps ci-cd release pipeline to deploy, the npm custom command task `npm run start` persists indefinitely while attempting to start the **Node.js** application on a **Node.js Windows server**.
We are able to access `localhost:3000` while the release pipeline is in progress, but after cancelling the pipeline, we are unable to access localhost.
Is there any possibility of automatically finishing the release pipeline after the npm custom command task `npm run start` is able to listen on localhost?

[image: Release pipeline]

We are looking for any other possibilities, solutions, different methods, or commands after the **Node.js** server listens on localhost to finish the release pipeline.